# Add Kendo Tab in with AngularJS-Kendo Directives

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm new to both AngularJS and Kendo UI. I've noticed that Kendo has some AngularJS directives. https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo. I'm trying to figure out how to make a basic tab control using the kendo directives. Currently, I have the following:

```
<div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip>
  <ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    [Page 1]
  </div>
  <div>
    [Page 2]
  </div>
</div>
```

However, a tab control isn't rendering. I've verified that I've included angular-kendo.js. I have the Kendo-grid rendering. So I know I've wired up the kendo directives libraries correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your html is correct, and so is the directive. You must not have the directives injected correctly or else you are missing some of kendos js. Check out this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KQIJRrx5PGklnJfVeflk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an angular app instantiated.

Add the following to the top of your code snippet. This is the bare minimum needed to get your sample working:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app='app'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.1008/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('app',['kendo.directives']);
</script>
```